# how can I give an image an octagonal shape?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I'm creating a mobile App. In this app there is the user's profile and i would like give an an octagonal shape to the user's profile. For the moment I have just an image:

`<Image x:Name="ProfilePicture" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="Profile.png" TranslationY="50" VerticalOptions="End"/>`

how can I shape this image?

The result I would like to achieve is this:
[image]

a yellow outline and instead of the gift the user image

Comment: Which particular part of drawing an octagon are you struggling with? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't really know how to draw an octagon. I have tried superimposing the octagon image (only the outline) on the image uploaded by the user. Then I had no other ideas. it's my first App so I don't know how to move.

Comment: Have you tried a `<Path>`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xaml doesn't support drawing shapes directly. You have several options:

1. Simple. Use shape image as resource. Put it all together with with grid or absolute layout.
2. Smart. Use Font Awesome icons in your XF. You can reuse other icons to reduce bitmaps in your app. Unfortunately octagonal shape is available only in PRO edition.
3. Heavy artillery. You can use Skiasharp or similar library to draw octagonal image with user image inside.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the first solution but the loaded image is not cut but the octagon is superimposed on it, which in most cases does not cover the image and the corners remain

Comment: It seems Xamarin.Forms has fairly decent support for SkiaSharp these days: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/

Comment: You could also use platform-specific code to draw the octagon.

Comment: Use png image that is transparent inside octagon and the rest of png has the same color as your page background color.

Comment: Aldorem can I then allow the user to drag the image so that he can decide how to center it?

Comment: For such a functionality you should use Skiasharp library. Then save created image locally to phone memory to reuse it later in your app.

Comment: thanks for the possible solutions, I will try them and tell you the best.